# Apache refused to open even changing port 80 and port 443

Tags: apache, xampp

I've read some post and tried to change it but unfortunately no change happened.

Here's the error returned:

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked
>   port, missing dependencies,  improper privileges, a crash, or a
>   shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs
>   and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more
>   help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

I've tried to listen on port 80 and port 443, but can't open it.

What did I miss?

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: couldn't start my apache server sir, can you help me

Comment: Nobody will help you unless you provide details (error, conditions, etc..). BTW this kind of question is offtopic here, it is more suited for serverfault.com

Comment: what error you are getting, do you have skype installed, might be it is port conflicts

Comment: No i don't have Sir

Comment: I updated the post above. i'll do search some solution but unfortunately same not working.

Answer (score 0):

Open **XAMPP Control Panel** and select **Config** under Apache. Select your *httpd.conf* and locate the following line.

```
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
Listen **xx**
```

Where you see **xx** change this to something like **8080** if it currently states **81**. Port 81 is commonly used by a few applications, as well as 443 so I tend to always change to 8080 by default, but your network may be different. You may obviously use `netstat` to see what ports may be available to you.

Restart **XAMPP** entirely as Apache is very fussy, then try starting Apache again.

Comment: I have made the changes for 80 and 443 ports but still shows the error